# Image comparison to Properties.Resources.image

Tags: c#, image, resources, comparison

Could you tell me why is the following condition false?

```
List<Image> SelectedImages = new List<Image>();
SelectedImages.Add(Properties.Resources.my_image);
if (SelectedImages[0] == Properties.Resources.my_image)     // false
{
    ...
}
```

Even if I write:

```
SelectedImages[0] = Properties.Resources.my_image;
if (SelectedImages[0] == Properties.Resources.my_image)     // false
{
    ...
}
```

How can I make this comparison work?

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what you consider to be equal? By that I mean what definition do you use for image equality. If both references are the same are the images equal? What if I have the same image in two places on my hdd, if the files had bitwise equality would those images be equal? The comparison isn't doing what you expect it to do, but I don't know what you expect it to do.

Comment: How about `Properties.Resources.my_image == Properties.Resources.my_image`? is this true or false?

Comment: `Properties.Resources.my_image == Properties.Resources.my_image` is also false...

Comment: Just get a reference to the image once in your class constructor and store it in a field.

Answer (score 3):

They're not equal because Properties.Resources makes a copy of the image and returns that copy back to your code. Everytime you get that image, you're effectively creating an entirely new Image object. It makes a copy because resources should ordinarily behave like constants. You wouldn't want your code to change the picture if you (for example) modified the picture in some way.

So what happens in your code? You end up comparing two *different* image objects that happen to contain the same data. .NET sees that you have two *different* objects and returns false. It doesn't do a "deep" comparision to see if the objects have the same data/state.

Here's a link to an article that explains what is going on at a high level: https://navaneethkn.wordpress.com/2009/10/15/understanding-equality-and-object-comparison-in-net-framework/

A quick way to workaround your problem would be to compare the Resource image and your SelectedImage Image pixel by pixel to see if they are "equal". This would obviously perform poorly. Another, more efficient way might be to build a dictionary and use a key to track where the image originally came from.

Comment: Thank you, very useful answer. I was also thinking about pixel by pixel comparison, but first I wanted to know whether there are more efficient solutions.

Comment: The two major approaches would be: 1) pixel by pixel comparison - or - 2) devise a key system to uniquely id each image's location in your array.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `Tag` property in the Image object.  You can store anything you want in there.  Just set up your image like this...

```
Image img_dbActive = MyApp.Properties.Resources.tray_icon_database_active;
img_dbActive.Tag = "tray_icon_database_active";

Image img_dbIdle = MyApp.Properties.Resources.tray_icon_database_idle;
img_dbIdle.Tag = "tray_icon_database_idle";

ToolStripStatusLabel lbl = new ToolStripStatusLabel("Database is doing something...", img_dbActive);
lbl.Image.Tag = "tray_icon_database_active";

if (lbl.Image.Tag == img_dbActive.Tag)
{
    //Images match
}
```